# Is it ethical for a professor to ask students to pretend to be gay

Tags: ethics

My professor is requiring students to pretend to be a closeted LGBT student for a day/or to perform actions that are “trans”. It’s worth 10% of the grade.

Edit: I’m queer and in my opinion this trivializes queer students and also creates unsafe situations for them

Edit for context: the assignment was not  discussed. Not voluntary. The course is “religion in modern culture” and in the religion department.

Comment: This question needs more context. What is the course about, in which field is this, has the assignment been discussed with the students in advance and is participation voluntary, etc.?

Comment: Not discussed. Not voluntary. The course is “religion in modern culture” and in the religion department.

Comment: What do you mean by "pretend to be a closeted LGBT student for a day/or to perform actions that are “trans”"?

Comment: Are you supposed to *imagine* yourself as if you were gay and then write about a hypothetical experience? Are you required to go to a gay bar? Pick up a gay date?

Comment: How would a closeted LGBT student be distinguishable from a heterosexual one? Sounds like the easiest 10% ever.

Comment: So would getting students / people to spend a day in a wheelchair be an issue - so they start to consider the issues?

Comment: And the professor is going to check that you "completed" the assignment... how? Is the professor going to follow all the students around (at once!) all day? Honestly I call BS on this question.

Comment: I think this is a really interesting question and not BS, but as it is it’s missing a lot of context and information so I voted to close as “unclear what you’re asking”. Can you please edit it to add more details? To give a meaningful answer, at minimum we’d need to know what precisely the professor is requiring the students to do. It would also help to understand your objection - how does the assignment “trivialize queer students” and in what way does it create unsafe situations for them? I’m asking to try to help and not to sound dismissive of you or your concerns.

Comment: @DanRomik This is a very obvious troll, designed to rile people up. I'm saying it is BS because I am questioning the fact that this event happened at all.

Comment: @Najib the fact that the prof can't know the students did the assignment honestly without following them around all day long is true for almost any homework assignment, so I don't understand how you see this as evidence that the question is made up. As I said, the question is missing important details, but you have a very poor basis on which to accuse OP of being a troll, so I'd say you are being a bit rude here. (Also, if the question were well-written, would it really matter if the scenario was real or not? Wouldn't you rather discuss an interesting made up question than a boring real one?)

Comment: @DanRomik 1. Unrealistic assignment (see my previous comment). 2. Zero details. 3. Controversial topic known to aggravate people. 4. Unregistered user, asked a single question, hasn't logged in since (and due to the way unregistered accounts work, will never log in again). 5. There is barely any question; it's a rant designed to produce more discussion. Maybe I'm wrong, but I've been on the internet long enough to smell trolls most of the time... But you can call me cynical if you want.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the idea is to teach mostly straight cisgender students about everyday LGBT experiences, going beyond an academic "we learned about this in class" understanding to an "I experienced genuine fear from simply walking down the street" understanding.  Basically, it's to develop empathy.

> ... this trivializes queer students and also creates unsafe situations for them.

The idea is probably *to make the students feel unsafe*: all the students.  And afterwards pose the question "if this level of safety is unacceptable for you (even for just a day), why is it acceptable for LGBT people?"

I get that it trivializes queer students by boiling their identities down to superficial acts.  It's also a bit weird that there's an implicit assumption that there are no LGBT students in the class.  But no assignment is perfect.

#### Is it ethical?

It's kind of edgy.

There would be valid religious objections to this assignment.  However, I find it hard to believe that a professor of religion is unprepared for this possibility.

It is possible a student could get attacked or arrested while conducting this assignment.  At the same time, this is the point: this "safety risk" is "everyday life" for LGBT people.

However, there's ways to "play it safe" by conducting the assignment from home (and it wouldn't be too dissimilar from the LGBT people who experience anxiety at a level where they are afraid to leave the house).  E.g. present yourself as an "identified" gender, and post an anonymized picture of yourself to a transgender website and see what they say (I used to do this when I was closeted, so it's an official Transgender Experience™).